# Run django app and php on the same domain using apache

Tags: python, django, apache, virtualhost

I am using a ubuntu with apache.
lets say i have this configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@mydomain.com
    ServerName mydomain.com
    ServerAlias www.mydomain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/mydomain.com/public_html
</VirtualHost>
```

i want the to add a django project that will be accessible through `www.test.com/dj`

i have tried this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@mydomain.com
    ServerName test.com
    ServerAlias www.mydomain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/mydomain.com/public_html
    WSGIScriptAlias /dj /home/me/public_html/djproject/djproject/djproject.wsgi
</VirtualHost>
```

when i try and open `www.mydomain.com/dj`
i get 403

> You don't have permission to access /dj on this server.

my question is how do i solve this and what is the right way of doing what i want.

Comment: Have you checked that: 1) You have the mod_wsgi module installed and have restarted Apache? 2) The user that is running Apache has permissions to read the WSGI file?  Check the Apache logs for more debugging details about the Forbidden error.

Comment: Yeah. You probably need to 'sudo chgrp WWW-data /path/to/dir'. Then make sure the chmod allows execution of the files as well.